# How can I run a code after another has already ended running?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In less than 1 second, I have to post something into a JSON file and then get that exact data updated. When running the code, it seems that I post the data in the JSON file but when I try to get it, it gets the old data, not the updated one.

How can i run get method after post method has ended running?

I ran this post method

```
import Game from "./components/Game/Game";

  class App extends React.Component {  
    postUserInfo(){
      fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/users" , {
        method: "post" ,
        mode: "cors",
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json",
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({username:this.state.userInput, bestscore:0})
      })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data => {console.log(data)}))
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    } 
 }
```

and then in the other class I run this get method right after the post method

```
class Game extends React.Component {
    getUserInfo() {
      fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/users" , {mode: "cors"})
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data => {
          this.setState({ usersInfoArray: data})
          var _userid = data[data.length-1].id;
          var _username = data[data.length-1].username;
          var _bestscore = data[data.length-1].bestscore;
          this.setState({ userid: _userid, username: _username, bestscore: _bestscore});
      }))
    } 
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.getUserInfo();
  this.render();
}
```

Comment: How are you calling `getUserInfo`? That's probably the most important part of code to share with us!

Comment: in componentDidMount

Comment: How are the two components related in your component tree?

Comment: class App extends React.Component  (Post) 

class Game extends React.Component (Get)

Comment: Is `Game` being called within `App`?

Comment: `Game` is imported in `App`

Comment: My guess is these two requests happen essentially at the same time; where and when is `postUserInfo()` called?

Comment: Would you be amicable to lifting the state up to the app level and just passing the correct data as props to the Game component?

Comment: Yea probably it is. It's called right before the get method is called. How can i run get method after post method is completly finished?

Comment: That depends on your setup; one way is to not mount `<Game>` until after the post method. Again, when is the post method called? When `<App>` is mounted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to maintain a `dataPosted` flag in App's state and pass that flag to the `Game` component. If the `dataPosted` flag is true, then load the data.

**App.jsx**

```
import Game from "./components/Game/Game";

class App extends React.Component {  
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { dataPosted: false }
  }

  postUserInfo(){
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/users" , {
      method: "post" ,
      mode: "cors",
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
      },
        body:JSON.stringify({username:this.state.userInput, bestscore:0})
      })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(data => {
         this.setState({ dataPosted: true })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    } 
 }   

  render() {
    <Game dataPosted={this.state.dataPosted} />
  }
}
```

**Game.jsx**

```
class Game extends React.Component {

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.props.dataPosted) {
      this.getUserInfo();
    }
  }

  getUserInfo() {
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/users" , {mode: "cors"})
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data => {
        this.setState({ usersInfoArray: data})
        var _userid = data[data.length-1].id;
        var _username = data[data.length-1].username;
        var _bestscore = data[data.length-1].bestscore;
        this.setState({ userid: _userid, username: _username, bestscore: _bestscore});
      }))
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. It worked. But now my timer messed up. I have a timer that counts every second with this code:

`this.myInterval = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(({ seconds }) => ({
        seconds: seconds + 1
      }))
    }, 1000)`

When use the componentDidUpdate, the page starts rendering way faster and causes a lot of lag. Do you know why?

Comment: Happy to help with that too... how's it messing up?

Comment: It starts rendering a lot with `render()`, don't know why

Comment: Fixed. ` componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.props.dataPosted && this.state.username === ' ') {
      this.getUserInfo();
    }
  }` 
It was looping getUserInfo(), thats why the lag

Answer (score 1):

I guess you may call postUserInfo() in another component then move to new Component
then after component mount, call getUserInfo()

Am i right?

If so

your navigate to(or create) other component logic must in postUserInfo()
near

```
.then((data => {console.log(data)}))
```